# video being played is getting cropped in video element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an mp4 video, I want it to fully cover the video element. The problem is that it showing as a cropped video

[image]

Code:

```
  <video
        loop
        muted
        width={600}
        height={400}
        
        // width= {window.innerWidth * 0.6 * 0.97}
        // height= {window.innerWidth * 0.6 * 0.5625 * 0.97}
        style={{  objectPosition: 'center',  objectFit: 'cover'
      }}
        
      >
        <source style={{ objectPosition: 'center',  objectFit: 'cover' }}
        src={
          "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"}
        ></source>

 </video>
```

I want that the video being played should occupy full space - that is it should cover the whole video element. Nothing should be cropped.

The problem is the video is getting copped by about half.

Comment: You do realize that objectFit:'cover' (had it worked) will always crop the video unless it happens to fit your dimensions perfectly proportionally? So do you want the video to be cropped (as long as it fills your "box")?

Do you need to have both a set height and and a set width? Or is a set width (maybe 100% of the parent element) enough. Because if you only require a set width you can adjust the height to to real proportions of the video. 

I am asking since a clear answer to these questions would make it easier to help you accomplish what you want.

Comment: @ThomasFrank  Yes I do realise, objectFit crops the video a little bit. But right now the video is getting cropped a lot ( getting cropped by about half ) - this is the problem. If the video gets cropped by small amount - that is OK. But it should not get cropped by half - this is happening now. I am also OK with like the video width is 100% of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes run perfectly fine when I convert it to plain HTML and JS. Your issue may be with some other styles that you use.

My HTML codes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Video Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video
            loop
            muted
            width="600"
            height="400"
            style="object-position: center; object-fit: cover;"
            controls
            >
            <source
                src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
                style="object-position: center; object-fit: cover;"
                >
        </video>
        <script>
            const video = document.querySelector("video");
            video.width = window.innerWidth * 0.6 * 0.97;
            video.height = window.innerWidth * 0.6 * 0.5625 * 0.97;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I ran this code. Sorry this code also has the same issue - the video is getting cropped by about half.